# How to maintain the same disk usage percentage in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My HDFS cluste consists of nodes with different storage capacity, and the node with lower capacity always get filled up and out of storage. Is there a way to configure the cluster so that each volume is around roughly the same percentage of usage?

Comment: Set this property `dfs.datanode.fsdataset.volume.choosing.policy` to `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.AvailableSpaceVolumeChoosingPolicy`. This enables storage balancing among the DataNode's volumes.

Comment: Thanks @alvits, I saw that config option before but used it wrong, fixed it and now everything works like a charm

Comment: How do you set the usage percentage when using `AvailableSpaceVolumeChoosingPolicy` ?